# React Native Navigation between screens from a FlatList

Tags: react-native

I want to navigate to a second screen with data from a FlatList but couldn't achieve this. Here is my code

Main Screen:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
var CatalogList = require("./catalogFlatList");
import { createBottomTabNavigator, SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

class MainScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#ed6b21" }}>
                <CatalogList />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

class SecondScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const text = navigation.getParam("text", "ERROR");
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Text>
                    PASSED DATA IS!
                    {JSON.stringify(text)}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    .. some icons and colors ..
})
```

And CatalogList Module which draws the Main Screen

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    FlatList,
    ActivityIndicator,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";

class FlatListDemo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            data: [],
            error: null,
            refreshing: false,
            noData: false,
            tempData: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
    }

    makeRemoteRequest = () => {
      .. fetch some data from url ..
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={item.onItemPressed}>
                            <ListItem
                                title={`${item.name}`}
                                subtitle={`${item.companyname}`}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Second", {
                                        text: `${item.name}`
                                    });
                                }}
                                containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
                />
            </List>
        );
    }
}

export default FlatListDemo;
module.exports = FlatListDemo;
```

This can render FlatList but upon click on a ListItem it throws error of

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this2.props.navigation.navigate')
```

couldn't figure it out the logic behind this. I don't want to write all of my code in a single page.

Comment: Is your `CatalogList` inside the navigation stack that you use?

Comment: CatalogList is another file. Don't know how should i include it in the stack

Comment: Checkout the examples [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html), you need to first add a navigator, then register screens within it. Only the registered screens have access to navigation props.

Comment: but how do i register screens from another file. I mean i already created the buttombar stack and add 3 screens to it. But FlatList screen is another file so should i also create and register stacks again if so shouldn't i need to paste same code for other screens also?

Comment: No, just export the file containing FlatList and import it to the navigator and register it. Try adding a [snack](http://snack.expo.io) if you face other issues.

Comment: yes i already export FlatList file and imported it, it renders the data in it.

Comment: Okay, do one thing `<CatalogList navigation={this.props.navigation}/>` add this to your `MainScreen` component

Comment: @PritishVaidya thank you!! please add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either pass the navigation props to your `Flatlist` component or use [`withNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav) **HOC** to get access to the navigation props

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ed6b21' }}>
  <CatalogList navigation={this.props.navigation} />
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: how do i pass the data and navigate to a screen that is not in createBottomTabNavigator?

Comment: Check the answer, you can pass it in similar way as [withNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this



 <FlatList 
         data={this.state.data}
         renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Second'{text:`${item.name}`})}}>
        <ListItem 
        title={`${item.name}`}
        subtitle={`${item.companyname}`}
        containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
        />

    </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
    />
```